# .Net MAUI: How to select single and multiple items using MVVM and CollectionView

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui, collectionviewsource, multipleselection

### Problem

I'm attempting a multi selection using `CollectionView` and `MvvM`.  The ([official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection) don't do the greatest job of differentiating between normal code-behind and MVVM, and for us noobies that hurts.

I can get the single selection working, but making the leap to multiple selection is beyond me.

I will show my working code for single selection and discuss how to make it work for multiple selection.  Maybe someone knows more than I?

### Single Selection

Here's the working code for single selection:

Pass an `ObservableCollection` of type `Person` to a ModelView.  Declare an instance of `Person` which will be the "selected object".

```
namespace Sandbox.ViewModel;

[QueryProperty("Persons", "Persons")]
public partial class SelectPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Person> persons;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Person selectedPerson;

    public SelectPageViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new();
    }
}
```

In the View, create a `CollectionView` and make some good guesses for its attributes:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Text="Select from List"/>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
                    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Person">
                <Grid>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

Back in the ViewModel, the `SelectionChanged` command: if the user is satisfied with their choice of `SelectedPerson`, I pass it back to the page from whence it came, otherwise I null the selection and return:

```
[RelayCommand]
private async Task SelectionChanged() 
{
    bool keepSelection = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(SelectedPerson.Name, "Keep this selection?", "Yes", "No");
    if (keepSelection)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> throwParam = new()
        {
            { "SelectedPerson", SelectedPerson }
        };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", throwParam);
    }

    // else clear the selection and return
    SelectedPerson = null;
    return;
}
```

### Multiple Selection

After much wrestling, here is working code.  Something *very important*: note the type of the `ObservableCollection` that is used to in the binding to the collection (hint, it's `Object`).

### Another Edit (my current code)

My current code is the same as the above code, but I will show both ViewModel and View in total, plus screenshots of the List that's supposed to be populated.

ViewModel:

```
namespace Sandbox.ViewModel;

[QueryProperty("Persons","Persons")]
public partial class SelectPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Person> persons;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Object> selectedPersons;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Person selectedPerson;

    public SelectPageViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new();
        SelectedPersons = new();
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    private void SelectionChanged()
    {
// every time something is selected, the object is added to SelectedPersons automagically.
        int a = SelectedPersons.Count; // will +1 every time
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Sandbox.ViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Sandbox.Model"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:SelectPageViewModel"
             x:Class="Sandbox.View.SelectPage"
             Title="SelectPage">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" Padding="10">
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Text="Select from List"
               FontSize="Large"
               FontAttributes="Bold" />

        <CollectionView Grid.Row="1"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"                    
                        SelectionMode="Multiple"
                        SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPersons, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Person">
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontSize="Medium" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: the official docs do mention it: "When the SelectionMode property is set to Multiple, multiple items in the CollectionView can be selected. When items are selected, the **SelectedItems** property is set to the selected items."

Comment: `SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPerson}"` you are binding to the single object, not to the collection

Comment: Ah, I get it.  I need to reference the collection.  OK, I did that, and the exception is not happening.  How to I access the selected items that have the changed properties?  In the docs it explains in in code-behind, but I don't see the analog to MVVM.

Comment: use the VM collection its bound to

Comment: I don't understand.  The collection is bound to an `ObservableList<Person>`.  I created the properties for the objects in that list.  No properties have been added to them.

Comment: use whatever `SelectedItems` is bound to

Comment: It's bound to `ObservableList<Person>`.  When I'm inside that method, the properties for `Person` are the same as they ever have been.  How could it add properties, anyways?

Comment: that property should contain the list of selected items

Comment: What property are you referring to? (I edited the question to reflect the changes to the XAML)

Comment: if you have `SelectedItems="{Binding BobsSelectedItems}"` then the VM property `BobsSelectedItems` should contains the items you have selected, assuming it is the right type.  I have no idea what you think `SelectedItems="{Binding Source={x:Reference collection}}"` will do

Comment: For the second question, it's referenceing the collection (I named the collection "collection"... `x:Name="collection"`

Comment: IF there's another way to Bind to the collection, I don't know it.

Comment: IF that's not how to bind to the collection, then how do I do it?

Comment: Why are you binding to a UI object?  Just create a property in your VM and bind to it.  Exactly like you are binding to the `ItemsSource`.  You are making this 100x harder than it needs to be

Comment: That's because I'm totally confused.  we're sufferening from terminology problems:  my usage of the term "property" is different than yours.

Comment: To me, a property is something that an object has.  The object "Person" has the property "Name", etc.

Comment: your VM is an object that has properties.  What do you think `[ObservableProperty]` does?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: So if I bind `SelectedItems` to the `ObserbableCollection<Person>`, that's fine, but... it still doesn't change the fact that I don't know what property to look for in the method.

Comment: Like, when I'm stepping thourhg the code, and I get into the method `SelectionChanged`, how do I know what objects were selecteed?  (that's after I changed to `SelectedItems="Persons"`, which is the list that the Collection is bound to)

Comment: They will be contained in `SelectedPersons` (or whatever you named it).  See my example below.

Comment: They're not.  The list that I bound the collection to is called `Persons`.  Each `Person` in `Persons` has two properties, "Name" and "age".  When I'm in the `SelectionChanged` method and I look through the `Person` objects in `Persons`, those are the only properties that are there.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Person.  This has to do with the **properities of the VM** you are binding to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a property in your VM (note that it needs to be a collection of **object** (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72661068/net-maui-mvvm-binding-a-selecteditemcommand-and-selecteditemparameter-from-a-co))

```
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<Person> persons;

[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<object> selectedPersons;
```

initialize them

```
public SelectPageViewModel()
{
    Persons = new();
    SelectedPersons = new();
}
```

then bind your `CollectionView` to it

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
                SelectionMode="Multiple"
                SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPersons}"
                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}">
```

if the user selects 3 rows, those 3 objects will be contained in `SelectedPersons`.  `SelectedPersons` will be a subset of your `ItemsSource` `Persons`

```
[RelayCommand]
private void SelectionChanged()
{
    foreach(var p in SelectedPersons)
    {
       if (p is Person person)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name} is selected");
        }
    }
}

[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<Person> persons;

[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<object> selectedPersons
```

Comment: That's exactly how I thought it was supposed to work from the beginning!  Sadly, it's not working.

Comment: My code is exactly like what you have up there, and the `SelectedPersons` list is always zero.

Comment: Jason, I appreciate your time.  I think I can come up with a workaround.

Comment: Need Mode=TwoWay right? `SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPersons, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: I added that, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: see my last edit, I just tested this and it works

Comment: I believe you.  I don't know why it's not working for me.  I just displayed all of my code in the question above, with included screenshots. The problem must be in something I missed.

Comment: Please read the complete answer.  I made an important change based on another SO question

Comment: You, sir, are a saint.  I wonder why it's gotta be a generic object?  Anyways, thank you, fellow Houstonian.  I just learned a lot.

Comment: Oh, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection says `SelectionItems` is of type `IList<object>` when the selected items is a list.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection states:

- `SelectedItems`, of type `IList<object>`, the selected items in the list. This property has a default binding mode of `OneWay`, and has a `null` value when no items are selected.
- `SelectionChangedCommand`, of type `ICommand`, which is executed when the selected item changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.collectionview?view=net-maui-7.0 states:

- `SelectedItems` (Inherited from `SelectableItemsView`)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.selectableitemsview.selecteditems?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-controls-selectableitemsview-selecteditems states:

```cs
public System.Collections.Generic.IList<object> SelectedItems { get; set; }
```

This basically means when `SelectionMode=Multiple` it is expecting an `IList<object>` which it will update accordingly, but, you will need to implement `SelectionChangedCommand` to see changes in the selection.

```
// MainPage.xaml.cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace StackOverflow.Maui.Mvvm.SelectMultiple;

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public IList<Person> Persons { get; }
        = new List<Person>("Tom,Dick,Harry"
                               .Split(",")
                               .Select(s => new Person() { Name = s }));
    public IList<object> SelectedPersons { get; } = new List<object>();
    public ICommand CheckCommand { get; }     
    public MainPage()
    {
        CheckCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            string SelectedPersonsText = string.Join(", ", SelectedPersons.Select(p => ((Person)p).Name));
            Debug.WriteLine($"SelectedPersons = [{SelectedPersons.Count}] {SelectedPersonsText}");
        });
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CheckCommand));
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow.Maui.Mvvm.SelectMultiple"
             x:Class="StackOverflow.Maui.Mvvm.SelectMultiple.MainPage">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
                    SelectionMode="Multiple"
                    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPersons}"
                    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding CheckCommand}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                <Frame>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Mr. Quan, one of the parameters of this question was MVVM, for us newbies who've decided to learn one way and haven't learned the other.

Comment: Hi @Bob, don't get me wrong, I think it was a good question, since, I also didn't fully understand how the `CollectionView` worked for `SelectionMode=Multiple`. So, I thought I checked it out, and, I found my result to, perhaps, offer a different enough perspective to the accepted answer, hence, why I posted it. Whilst I didn't explain some of the choices I made, I left it all in there, since, you could take advantage of anything presented.

Comment: Mr Quan, it's all good.  In fact, your note got me to ponderin' and I ended up figuring it out.